# Are memory and thread managers on Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7 Home/Prof/Ultimate same?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, memory, threads

I was asking [one question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17264/sql-server-2008-r2-on-windows-7-x64-professional-what-are-the-downsides) on DBA site, and I got a [reply](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/17274/8503), that implies, that Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7 Home/Prof/Ultimate have different memory and thread managers. Is this correct?